# Angularjs losing scope in same line ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, templates, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm having trouble replacing the {{path}} within the template tag in the ng-include. If I put the tag inside the template anywhere else works perfectly, however I need to work within the include-ng to get the base path. Anyone have an idea.

Html with MVC

```
 <div ng-controller='menuCtrl'>
                <nav id="menu">
                    <ul>
                        <li ng-repeat="item in itens" ng-include="'@(ViewBag.path)Areas/System/scripts/templates/menu.html'" repeat-done></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
 </div>
```

App.js

```
var myApp = angular.module('mobsupplyApp', []).directive('repeatDone', function () {
    return function (scope) {
        if (scope.$last === true) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                $("#menu").jarvismenu();
            });
        }
    };
});

myApp.controller('menuCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
    $http.get(path + "api/menu").success(function (data, status) {
        $scope.itens = data;
        $scope.path = path;
    });
}]);
```

Template.html

```
<a href="{{ item.url }}" title="{{ item.description }}"><i class="fa fa-lg fa-fw {{ item.image }}"></i> <span class="menu-item-parent">{{ item.description }}</span></a>

<ul ng-if="item.itens">
    <li ng-repeat="item in item.itens" ng-include="'{{ path }}Areas/System/scripts/templates/menu.html'"></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: is it supposed to be item in itens?

Comment: If I put the path inside and outside of the template-ng Include works perfectly, I'm just having trouble in this specific case.

Comment: Well that doesn't answer my question at all.